# Blend 20000 small CIImages in CoreImage

Tags: ios, image, image-processing, core-image

I have 20000 small filtered images (transformed and cropped from original  Image with >> 8000*8000). These images have different extent, I want to blend this images with normal blending, but have a stack overflow error.
It's happened because CIImage it is a receipt but not a image, and then I blend images by pairs, Core Image generate receipt recursive.
Part of the stack:

```
#0  0x000000018519f0c0 in CI::Affine::applyToRect(CGRect) const ()
#1  0x00000001851a1b90 in CI::AffineImage::apply_roi(CGRect, CI::Context*) ()
#2  0x00000001851a1bd4 in CI::AffineImage::apply_roi(CGRect, CI::Context*) ()
#3  0x00000001851a1bd4 in CI::AffineImage::apply_roi(CGRect, CI::Context*) ()
#4  0x00000001851a2b28 in CI::ApplyImage::apply_roi(CGRect, CI::Context*) ()
#5  0x00000001851a2b28 in CI::ApplyImage::apply_roi(CGRect, CI::Context*) ()
#6  0x00000001851a2b28 in CI::ApplyImage::apply_roi(CGRect, CI::Context*) ()
#7  0x00000001851a2b28 in CI::ApplyImage::apply_roi(CGRect, CI::Context*) ()
#8  0x00000001851a2b28 in CI::ApplyImage::apply_roi(CGRect, CI::Context*) ()
#9  0x00000001851a2b28 in CI::ApplyImage::apply_roi(CGRect, CI::Context*) ()
#10 0x00000001851a2b28 in CI::ApplyImage::apply_roi(CGRect, CI::Context*) ()
#11 0x00000001851a2b28 in CI::ApplyImage::apply_roi(CGRect, CI::Context*) ()
#12 0x00000001851a2b28 in CI::ApplyImage::apply_roi(CGRect, CI::Context*) ()
#13 0x00000001851a2b28 in CI::ApplyImage::apply_roi(CGRect, CI::Context*) ()
<.....>
#2387   0x00000001851a1bd4 in CI::AffineImage::apply_roi(CGRect, CI::Context*) ()
#2388   0x00000001851b28c8 in ___ZN2CI7Context16can_render_imageEPNS_5ImageERK6CGRectmm_block_invoke ()
#2389   0x0000000101801a3c in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#2390   0x000000010180d5f0 in _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke ()
#2391   0x00000001851b27e0 in CI::Context::can_render_image(CI::Image*, CGRect const&, unsigned long, unsigned long) ()
#2392   0x00000001851c221c in CI::image_get_cgimage(CI::Context*, CI::Image*, CGRect, CGColorSpace*, CI::PixelFormat) ()
#2393   0x0000000185187b58 in -[CIContext createCGImage:fromRect:format:colorSpace:] ()
```

I will get UIImage every 100-1000 steps, and write it to the disk, but don't think that it is very good solution (long tome to get image and write to the disk), and late blend the generated images.

How I can blend MANY CIImages without store parts to the disk?

P.S.
I process the original image with > 8000*8000 size.

**UPD**
Main task is implement a mesh filter. I can create with OpenGL by using of Meth with Texture. My mesh has 100*100 vertexes. But I can't apply it to big images on iOS, for example, I can't process an image with 8000*8000 size. I know that I can process big images with CoreImage.
I've implemented filters for process one triangle (transformation and trimming, after that I've tried to combine small processed images to generate result processed image. But if I do not write parts to disc, then I have overflow of call stack, because result image is generated with recursion algorithm.
My solution is not very quick for production, but I can't find other solution to implement mesh filter.
[Example of my filter.](https://youtu.be/aC6UwO-L1Is)

Comment: Are you trying to blend 20,000 images into a single resulting image? Or perform the same operation on 20,000 images with 20,000 output images? Perhaps some code would show what you are doing more precisely.

Comment: If I initiate CIImages from URL (from file on the disc), I can blend them. If I apply some filter for the images, I can't blend them with error

Comment: Main task is process any part of source image (near 20000) with different filters config (transformation) and get result image with transformed parts.

Comment: Now I process any part and write it on the disc after that. After I can crate CIImages from the files and blend them to the result image. (Also I store the extents of the transformed parts.)

Comment: I'm still not fully certain what you are trying to do, are you just trying to batch process a lot of images with different filters? Would love to see a minimal example of the code you are trying in order to help out.

Comment: I'll add video of my OpenGl implementation working.

Comment: Very cool stuff. How related are all the images to each other? Can you process each image independently from all the others? Or is there a cascading relationship between all the images?

Comment: Any triangle has bounds, I use it to determine a extent of source and a extent of result image's part. When I have these datas I can blend parts to get result image. And yes I can, I process any small part independently from others. I cut the part from the source image and process it, after that I save part to disc with a result extent. A cascading relationship is not needed for this task. But if I will not save parts to disk before blend them, I'll get a stack overflow error.

Comment: On the application start I have only one image that I want to process with the mesh.